# ImageView not moving correctly when dragged

Tags: android, touch-event

Basically i have this code where i can drag an imageView horizontally it currently works fine until i release and try to move it again it dosen't really follow my touch it just goes in front of the touch or just goes somewhere where i didn't drag .

```
 micImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        final int x = (int) motionEvent.getRawX();
                        final int y = (int) motionEvent.getRawY();

                        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                                        view.getLayoutParams();


                                xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                                yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;

                                startRecording();

                                break;

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                                break;

                            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                                        .getLayoutParams();
                                layoutParams.leftMargin = 0;
                                layoutParams.topMargin = 0;
                                layoutParams.rightMargin =  xDelta - x;
                                layoutParams.bottomMargin =  yDelta - y;
                                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                break;

                        }

                        mainLayout.invalidate();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
```

i want the imageView to follow my finger correctly and thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much simpler way to achieve the same result:

```
micImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDelta = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                yDelta = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                startRecording();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xDelta).y(event.getRawY() + yDelta).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
       return true;
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe your issue is caused by not setting the default boolean to false.

---

**Edit**: Answering the question in the comments.

You can achieve this by doing the following:
(I have not tested this, but it should work.)

```
int originalX = micImage.getX();
int originalY = micImage.getY();

micImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                xDelta = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                yDelta = view.getY() - event.getRawY();
                startRecording();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xDelta).y(event.getRawY() + yDelta).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                view.animate().x(originalX).y(originalY).setDuration(0).start();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
           return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! thank you very much. Just one more question is there a way that it returns to it's initial position once the touch is released ?

Comment: You are welcome. You will have to keep track of the original position, then you can call `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:` and set it to the original position by calling `view.animate().x(originalX).y(originalY).setDuration(0).start();`

Comment: I edited my answer, I have not tested this, but it should be working.